# Like Operator in a Trigger

Tags: apex, operators

I am editing an existing Trigger where I need to reference a field that starts with 'Check In @'

So I tried using the LIKE operator but it gives an error:

```
((t.Subject=='Store Check-In' || t.Subject LIKE :'Check In @%')  && t.Completed_Date__c != Null)
```

So I tried using contains.  This did not give an error but it also did not update my field

```
if ((t.Subject=='Store Check-In' || t.Subject.contains('Check In @%'))  && t.Completed_Date__c != Null)
```

The logic is supposed to be if an activity subject = 'Store Check-In' OR starts with 'Check In @' AND the complete_Date is not Null then do soemthing.

Any recommendations would be appreciated.
Cheers,
M

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `startsWith` [function](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_string.htm#apex_System_String_startsWith) in String class

```
t.Subject.startsWith('Check In @')
```

So the full if condition would be

```
if ((t.Subject=='Store Check-In' || t.Subject.startsWith('Check In @')) && t.Completed_Date__c != Null)
```